Can I use sql phrase that "alter session [session id] stop grace" in mybatis mapper?
I use update tage in mybatis mapper.
<update id="stopSessionGracefully" parameterType="com.project.dao.dto.StopSessionReqDaoDto">
    ALTER SESSION #{sessionId} STOP GRACE
</update>

but it's not work.
is it impossible to use "alter session ... " sql phrase in mybatis mapper?

Please edit the question and 1) include DB/driver versions and 2) explain how it does not work exactly. If there is an exception, add the entire stack trace (as text, not image).

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
